# Why there is no biholomorphism between complex plane and unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Why there is no biholomorphism between complex plane and the unit disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entire non-constant functions are unbounded by Liouvilles theorem. But holomorphic maps $f : \mathbb{C} \to D$ are necessarily bounded, thus constant. And therefore not bijective of course.